# New pixel 2- turning on shows battery and then horizontal purple line

Tags: boot, hardware, google-pixel-2

I just bought a new Pixel 2. I opened the box, turned it on, and it showed a white battery with the charge symbol, and then that disappeared, and 2 small colinear horizontal purple lines briefly flash in the middle center of the screen, and then the screen turned black again.

Did I get a dead unit out of the box? Or do I need to charge it first? Or do something else?

Edit:
I had tried leaving it plugged in for 10 min and nothing continued to show up on the screen. When I tried turning it on, it was same result. I currently own a Pixel, and when it dies and you plug it in, it at least turns the screen and shows the battery charge icon. This one never did this.

I ended up exchanging it and the new phone booted up straight to the google screen. I think the old one was a defective unit, but cannot confirm 100% since I didn't try leaving it plugged in for more than the ten minutes.

Comment: I had tried leaving it plugged in for 10 min and nothing continued to show up on the screen. When I tried turning it on, it was same result. I currently own a Pixel, and when it dies and you plug it in, it at least turns the screen and shows the battery charge icon. This one never did this. I ended up exchanging it and the new phone booted up straight to the google screen. I think the old one was a defective unit.

Comment: Oh.. might as well  answer your question...all the best